# How would I convert a PNG Image into a byte array?

Tags: gwt, png

Using GWT I would like to read a PNG image and have the data accessible to me as a decoded byte array.

On the client side I get the image using an ImageBundle, I then instantiate an Image and call setUrl.

At this point, how do I get the image byte array from the image?

Comment: Can you just read the file? It should be all numbers in pixels

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920701/how-do-i-get-png-image-data-as-a-decoded-byte-array-using-gwt) for answer. Kaleb Brasee`s answer has code to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Javascript (and hence GWT) do not have access to images' data when images are presented as html images (i.e. as `<img>` tag or css background image).

What you *could* do is load image data via RPC, process it, Base64 encode it and then create image via embedded url: `"data:image/png;base64,..yourBase64Datahere.."`

If you are trying to do some visual manipulation you should consider:

1. Manipulating image on the server.
2. Using html [`canvas`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp) or [`svg`](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp).

Comment: You can create a canvas element add the image to the context"d and read the data of the context2d.